# How do you tell a professor you interviewed with you will be going to a different program?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I had an email exchange and interview with this professor and I feel like I should tell her I've been accepted elsewhere to my first choice program, but writing the words down and getting the tone right are hard.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, that's a hard letter to write. But she will have gotten letters like this before. Thank her, say you would have enjoyed working with her but that you have found another position that suits you better or better fits your interests.

If you want to edit your question to show us a draft you may get useful feedback.

Write her soon, so she can offer the job to someone else.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I should probably add that this is for a masters program, so it isn't quite as serious and I haven't started, I've only considered applying.

Comment: If you can add some mild complement to the mail, provided it is true, it is also good in general. "interesting work", "helpful support", ...

Comment: Not as important for a masters' program, but if you're working in the same area and likely to run in to each other, it can kind to mention that; "I appreciate the time you put into evaluating my application, and hope to meet you in person sometime at $CONFERENCE". Reasonable professors will welcome you into the community, even if you're doing your studies elsewhere.